# Repeated cells while scrolling uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am developing news feed and I am using uitableview to display data. I am loading each cell data synchronically in other thread and use protocol method to display loaded data:

```
func nodeLoaded(node: NSMutableDictionary) {
    for var i = 0; i < nodesArray.count; ++i {
        if ((nodesArray[i]["id"] as! Int) == (node["id"] as! Int)) {
            nodesArray[i] = node
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I scroll my uitableview (while data synchronically loading), some of my cells repeats (8 row has same content like first, or 6 row has the same content like second row). When I scroll after some time (I suppose after data is loaded) then all become normal.
I looking for answers and found that I have to check if cell is nill at  cellForRowAtIndexPath, but in swift my code is different then in objective C:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: NewsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsCell
    var node = nodesArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    if (node["needLoad"] as! Bool) {
        dbHelper.getNode(node["id"] as! Int, hash: node["id"] as! Int, tableName: DbHelper.newsTableName, callback: self)
    } else {
        cell.id = node["id"] as! Int
        cell.titleLabel.text =  node["title"] as? String
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = node["description"] as? String
        cell.imgView.image = WorkWithImage.loadImageFromSD((node["image"] as! String))
    }
    return cell
}
```

Also I can't check if cell == nil bcs of binary error (NewsCell can't be nil).

What should I do? Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you seem to have created a separate class for UITableViewCell. The problem with your code is that you are not resetting the labels when reuse happens.

Oveeride prepareForReuse method in your custom UITableviewCell class and reset your interfaces there. That should fix the issue.